# Show post type where category equals page title

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to list posts from a custom post type 'article' on several pages where the post category matches the page title. So on the products page there would be list all the articles with the category products, reviews page there would be a list of all articles with the category reviews, etc.

No posts are returned when I use category_name, and all posts are returned without it.

```
    <?php
    // Get articles that have a category that matches the page title (ie: On pagination page get articles with pagination category)
    $pageTitle = get_the_title();

    $postType = 'article';

    $args= array(
      'post_type' => $postType,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'category_name' => $pageTitle

      );

    $articles = new WP_Query($args);

    if( $articles->have_posts() ) {
      while ($articles->have_posts()) : $articles->the_post(); ?>
        <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
            <p class="tags"><?php the_category()?></p>

        <?php
      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'category_name' parameter requires you use the category slug, not the name. You could get the category ID instead from the name...

```
$catID = get_cat_ID( $pageTitle );
```

... then use the 'cat' parameter in your query.

```
'cat' => $catID,
```